# Using Workbox to manage caches with several service worker clients

Tags: service-worker, workbox

I'm recently implement a service workers on our site with workbox. Due to the structure of our project we're implementing a service worker for each page for instance:

- /foo/XXX/
- /foo/XYZ/
- /foo/XXY/

This is causing that we're creating a service worker for each page. 
On the other hand, we're using precaching in our build process in order to precache css and js assets.

I know workbox creates two caches, one for precaching and the other one for the runtime. Becuase we have several service worker our customer have a new cache entry when they visit a new page

- workbox-precache-https://www.example.com/foo/XXX-https://www.example.com
- workbox-precache-https://www.example.com/foo/XYZ-https://www.example.com
- workbox-precache-https://www.example.com/foo/XXY-https://www.example.com

I know workbox provides an option to set the name for the cache.

```
workbox.core.setCacheNameDetails({
  prefix: 'my-app',
  suffix: 'v1',
  precache: 'custom-precache-name',
  runtime: 'custom-runtime-name'
});
```

My question is, can I use this option to set the cache name as unique ? My approach is that all assets are in the same cache so workbox will be in charge to delete duplicated and manage the cache. Does it make sense?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If you call `workbox.core.setCacheNameDetails({suffix: 'my-suffix'})` at the very start of your service worker script, and you do that for each service worker registered on your origin, that would be enough to have all of the service workers use a common cache for their precached assets. (Normally the scope of the currently service worker is used as the suffix, to prevent collisions and ensure that each service worker got its own cache, so you'd be overriding that behavior.)

But... I'd be hesitant to actually do this, or at least to test thoroughly before you do, as you're opening yourself up to possible issues. Some things that I'd worry about:

- Normally, the `install` and `activate` service worker lifecycle events are used to trigger downloading new assets (`install`) and deleting out of date assets (`activate`). The `activate` step will, by default (unless you're using `skipWaiting`) not fire until after all tabs with active clients are closed, to ensure that nothing is deleted which is still being used by a tab. If you have multiple service workers, each with their own scope and their own lifecycle events, managing the same cache using precaching, then one service worker's `activate` event might fire while a tab is open still controlled by a different service worker. This could cause entries to be deleted from the precache when they still might be used by that second tab.
- I'd be worried about any relative URLs in your precache manifest, as each of those relative URLs would be resolved using the location of the current service worker as the base. If each of the paths of your site have different URL structures, or if `/foo/XXX/app.js` is fundamentally different than `/foo/XYZ/app.js`, then an entry of `./app.js` in a precache manifest will end up being pretty dangerous if you share a single cache.

What I'd recommend as an alternative, if you really can't go with a single, higher-level service worker, is not to force all the precached assets into a single cache but instead maintain separate, potentially smaller precaches for each service worker, and then use [runtime caching](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/route-requests#handling_a_route_with_a_workbox_strategy) with a common `cacheName` parameter to share the resources that you know are common. I think that's much less likely to be error prone.